# Why can I see server response in my signed apk android?

Tags: android, apk, android-keystore, signed-apk, android-signing

I generated a signed apk using a .jks file for release.
It got uploaded on playstore for beta testing also. But if I use the app with my andorid-studio I can see the server responses in my log-cat which should not be the case as far as I know.

When I generate the apk, i can see the build type release

[image: Screenshot]

and my build.gradle of module is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "PACKAGE_NAME"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    multiDexEnabled true

    versionName "1.0.2"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/menu']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/2', 'src/main/java/PACKAGE_NAME/Models']
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}
```

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Post your app module's `build.gradle`.

Comment: @azizbekian edited.. please have a look :)

Comment: Just to be sure: Your are using Log.d (or whatever) and not System.out, right? :)

Comment: @Prexx I am also using system.out, yes

Comment: Are the logs you see in your release apk the ones you log with "System.out"?

Comment: @Prexx yepp! all of 'em

Comment: Then why not changing them to Log.d? :) That should do the trick. Otherwise write a custom Log class and handle the logger output with BuildConfig.DEBUG.

Comment: @Prexx woah! didn't know these things also affect.. so cool.. Thanks buddy.. will try it out!!

Answer (score 0):

The order in terms of verbosity, from least to most is ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, VERBOSE. Verbose should never be compiled into an application except during development. Debug logs are compiled in but stripped at runtime. Error, warning and info logs are always kept.

You can use your logs like below

```
public class AppLog {

    public static void info(String tag, String message) {
       if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(tag, message);
      }
   }
}
```

Refer : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html